# SQL in Rails - Chaining "AND"

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I don't get why SQL does not like my query:

```
@unreadmessages = Message.find(:all, :conditions => ["receiver_id = ? AND receiver_archived = ? AND read = ?", self.current_user, "No", "No"])
```

There is a different way to write this, but I want to keep my style consistent (this one avoids SQL injections, I gather.).

Thanks for your input!

Comment: Hi Smirhage,

    Mysql::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'read = 'No')' at line 1: SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE (receiver_id = 28 AND receiver_archived = 'No' AND read = 'No') 

I already found a workaround for this issue (in this place) but I am wondering what causes the error.

Comment: Thanks for your answers - I didn't know about the read part or the tics. I will use boolean & change the column name.

BTW:

unreadmessages = Message.find(:all, :conditions => { :receiver_id => self.current_user, :receiver_archived => "No", :read => "No"})

Seems to work.

Have a nice weekend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Read" is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL. I recommend renaming the column. Alternatively you can put it in back-tics every time it is referenced.

```
@unreadmessages = Message.find(:all, :conditions => ["receiver_id = ? AND receiver_archived = ? AND `read` = ?", self.current_user, "No", "No"])
```

I recommend renaming though.

Comment: Good catch.  I missed that detail entirely.

Comment: or do not use reserved words for field names

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that you're not really storing the word "No" in your database to track true/false.  If you're using a boolean or bit, try this.

```
@unreadmessages = Message.find(:all, :conditions => ["receiver_id = ? AND receiver_archived = ? AND read = ?", self.current_user.id, false, false])
```

Edit:
See what ryanb says about "read," and please consider what I said about your columns if this is a new app and you have control over what the database schema looks like.